# Cannot add the 15th collection to Sails Mongo

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am getting a failure whenever I try to add my 15th collection.

> errorType': 'Error', 'errorMessage': 'Callback was already called.', 'trace': ['Error: Callback was already called.', '
> at eval (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/async/dist/async.js?:843:36)', '
> at eval (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/system/validate-datastore-connectivity.js?:31:14)', '
> at eval (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js?:952:35)', '
> at Function.handlerCbs.error (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js?:742:26)', '
> at parley.retry (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js?:1088:49)', '
> at parley (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/parley/lib/parley.js?:140:5)', '
> at Object.runFn [as getConnection] (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js?:461:23)', '
> at validateDatastoreConnectivity (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/system/validate-datastore-connectivity.js?:27:25)', '
> at eval (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js?:722:18)', '
> at Object.success (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/index.js?:356:16)', '
> at eval (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js?:1517:30)', '
> at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js?:1155:14)', '
> at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js?:913:12)', '
> at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js?:845:10)', '
> at eval (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js?:303:7)', '
> at eval (webpack://mnUvr-api/./node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js?:954:24)'

This is happening when I get to my 15th collection, I haven't yet decided to create a blank project and see if it repro's in that way.

```
export const connectToDatabase = (): Promise<void> => {
  if (orm) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Waterline.start(config, (err: unknown, _orm: Waterline.Waterline) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Could not start up the ORM:\n", err);
        return reject(err);
      }

      orm = _orm as Waterline;

      collections = {
        Syllabus: getModel("syllabus"),
        Clazz: getModel("clazz"),
        Move: getModel("move"),
        User: getModel<UserModel>("user"),
        Family: getModel("family"),
        Video: getModel("video"),
        ClazzLevel: getModel<ClazzModel>("clazzlevel"),
        ClazzMembership: getModel("clazzmembership"),
        syllabusOwnership: getModel("syllabusownership"),
        series: getModel("series"),
        SchoolOwnership: getModel("schoolownership"),
        School: getModel("school"),
        Product: getModel("product"),
        StudentProgress: getModel("studentprogress"),
        seriesMembership: getModel("seriesMembership"),
      };

      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

I have a pretty vanilla connection to database, using Sails-Mongo 2.0. I have been able to use 14 collections without any issue, but I went to add another collection to use, and suddenly I get this error, and I have no idea why.

I don't believe that there is a problem with the model itself, as I have stripped all of the attributes to make it as boring as possible, with no syntax errors, and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future person, the issue was with the model name having a capital letter in it.

```
seriesMembership: getModel("seriesMembership"),
```

That fails, while the following succeeds:

```
seriesMembership: getModel("seriesmembership"),
```